# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus at Discontinuities

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**
Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x \neq 1$, and $f(x) = 1$ if $x=1$
Let $F(x) = \int_0^xf $. At which points is $F'(x) =f(x)$?

**Answer**
Can I get a check to see if my answer is correct?

I understand that if a function $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, and we let $h = g$ except at finitely many $x_i \in [a,b]$, then $h$ is still integrable, and $\int_a^b g = \int_a^b h$.

Thus in the above question $F'(x)=0$ for all $x$, so $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all points except $x=1$.

Comment: The only problematic point is $x=1$ why? What is the domain of $F$? If it is $[0,1]$, then you can only check the left-hand limit of the difference quotient:$\frac{F(1-h)-F(1)}{h}=\frac{0-0}{h}=0$ so $F_-'(1)=0.$

Comment: Your answer is fine. We even have $F(x) =0$ for all $x$.

Comment: In any case you can have a look at FTC for general functions at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2149700/72031